# shifting a character in a text image by certain amount of pixels using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, text, pixel

We have a text document image and we want to move a word by certain amount of pixels. We wrote a code to just shift 1 letter at a time. But it was not clear. Is there any function or a code to move the pixels in MATLAB?

Comment: What about providing some code or basic examples? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move the entire line, you can use the [circshift()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/circshift.html) function. I don't think there is a code for moving just one part of an image, but if you have the coordinates of the word it can be done quite easily without.

If we have image b

```
b =

     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

and want to move the ones 3 places to the right, we can do

```
shift = 3; 
b(2:3,1+shift:2+shift) = b(2:3,1:2) //copy part of image
b(2:3,1:2) = 0 //Remove orignal part of image

b =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

You can also use a oneliner to shift the word, but it will overwrite anything between the word and where you are moving it

```
b(2:3,1:2+shift) = [zeros(2,shift) b(2:3,1:2)]
```